# Surface Pro 4 keyboard not responding and LEDs don't work

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, microsoft-surface-pro

My Surface Pro 4 Type Cover keyboard is not responding to any key presses or touchpad movements.  When I press the <kbd>Caps</kbd> or the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, the LEDs don't light up.  When I close the cover, the surface does not go to sleep like it's supposed to.  What can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, try disconnecting the keyboard, rebooting, and then reconnecting it.

If that doesn't help, make sure all your software and firmware is up to date by running Windows Update and checking for the latest updates.

If the keyboard is still not responding, try resetting the Surface firmware with these steps:

1. Shut down the Surface with the keyboard connected.
2. Hold down the "+" on the volume rocker and hold down the power button at the same time for about 20 seconds.  You'll see some stuff appear on the screen and then go away.  After the full amount of time, you'll be back at a black screen.

   (Protip:  This is also how you boot into the UEFI firmware.)
3. Power on the surface normally.

Resetting the firmware worked for me, so I'm not sure what other options are available after this.  You could try resetting Windows 10 (Settings > Update & security > Reset this PC > Get started), but I'm skeptical that would help.

Comment: Just had this issue with Surface Pro 3 and the solution worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For my experiences. Microsoft assistance help me update also no use.
Until recently i download Surface FIRMWARE update. Only able to fixed the issue.
Search your surface firmware and download it. One by one update.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add another possible solution: turn on Tablet mode in the quick actions, and then turn it off. I tried rebooting my device and such with no luck, and this is what helped.